# Filter data between two dates using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to filter data between two datetime. Here i am filtering the text file length in a directory..I need to filter text file between the selected date.

```
DateTime startDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime endDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
var queryList1Only = from i in di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)  
                     select i.Length;
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Where clause:

```
DateTime startDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime endDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

var queryList1Only = from i in di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
                     where i.GetCreationTime() > startDate && i.GetCreationTime() < endDate
                     select i.Length;
```

Instead of `GetCreationTime` you could use `GetLastWriteTime` or `GetLastAccessTime`.

I'd advise checking out a few examples using the where clause for a full understanding of how it all works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx#Y500).

Comment: Thanks for ur examples..Am new to LINQ..Will Learn from that LINK(Q)

Answer (score 5):

Well, how about a `where` clause?

```
var query = from i in di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
            where (i.GetCreationTime() > startDate && i.GetCreationTime() < endDate)
            select i.Length;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from fi in new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\path").EnumerateFiles("*.txt")
where fi.CreationTime > startDate and fi.CreationTime < endDate)
select fi.FullName;
```

Answer (score -1):

this work for me

var data = (from dataperiod in periods where dataperiod.DateStart <= (DateTime)finalDayNovelty && dataperiod.DateEnd >= (DateTime)initialDayNovelty select dataperiod ).ToList();